# ASHX Image Download on Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I am using ashx to serve images from a database, is there anyway to have a user click on a link that allows them to download the file on the computer. (IE it shows the Save Dialog) Like you download a file. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to prompt to save make sure you add the following line when creating the response:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment;filename=" + filename);
```

This will make the browser treat it like an attachment and prompt with the save dialog.

**EDIT:** Based on your comment make sure you are building your response correctly:

```
// set attachment header like above
// then you need to get your file in byte[] form
byte[] dataYouWantToServeUp = GetData();
// you can set content type as well
yourHttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
// serve up the response
yourHttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(dataYouWantToServeUp);
```

Comment: if i use this `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "evimg.ashx?id=18");` it tries to download the file evimg.ashx_id=18 which contains nothing.

Comment: @atrljoe you are probably not sending back the response correctly then.  Can you post the code that you are using to build your response?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the navigator is able to open type of the file you're trying to get, It will open it without asking. If for instants, the file is in `zip` format, the navigator is not able to open it and will ask you to download it.

Comment: But doing a Google Search I've found this:http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=8  about downloading any file to the browser .